# Profitability calculation

Tags: percentages

The question is as follows:

Question is that how many % profit in euros decreases.

Selling price of 70€ includes 40% profit. Price was decreased by 10%.
How many % does the profit decrease?

My math is

x*1.4=70

x=50

70*.9=63

63-50=13

13/20=.65 therefore profit is only 65% of the original profit,

meaning the profit has decreased 35%, this answer was assessed as incorrect.

What did I calculate incorrectly, and what is the correct way to solve this problem?

Comment: Based on a quick read your reasoning looks OK if the $40\%$ profit is based on the selling price. If it's based on the cost then a deleted answer is right. I think the question is ambiguous. Can you edit the question to tell us what the correct answer is?

Comment: I think it is not clear what "includes $40\%$ profit" means.  I initially read that as saying that $40\%$ of the sale price was profit but your interpretation is sensible as well.

Comment: @lulu I was about to add my comment to your deleted answer. Please undelete, and perhaps include both calculations.

Comment: 40 - 26 = 14 ?, i think the question is a bit unclear.

Comment: @EthanBolker  I have undeleted and provided two calculations though I think others are possible.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is unclear what "includes $40\%$ profit" means:

One interpretation:  "$40\%$ of the $70$ is profit"

Assuming that, let $C$ be your cost for the object.  We can compute $C$...we are given that $.4\times 70=28$ represented profit so $$C=70-28=42$$

If we reduce the selling price by $10\%$ we get a new selling price of $63$.  That would give us a profit of $$P_2=63-42=21$$

Thus the profit decreases from $28$ to $21$ which represents a drop of $7$ which is $25\%$ of the original profit.

Another interpretation "selling at $70$ would give a $40\%$ profit over your cost"

This is more akin to what was done in the original post.

Assuming that then we get, as in the post, that the original cost was $50$ and the profit $20$. If we reduce the selling price to $63$ then the new profit is $13$ which represents a $26\%$ profit over cost (which of course is still $50$).  Thus we have a $14\%$ drop in profit in this scenario.

Comment: Almost. In the second scenario the drop in profit is $35\%$ as the OP said. Your answer restates that as a $14$ _percentage point_ drop in profits, from $40\%$ to $26\%$.

Comment: @EthanBolker  Again, I think the phrasing is unclear.   I read "How many % does the profit decrease?" the way I computed it.  I don't think there is a mathematical disagreement here...just one of language.

Comment: I agree. And I think the OP knows just what he's doing, better than the questioner. I particularly like his $1.4x=70$ for finding the cost.

Answer (score 0):

As you calculated:

- Old selling price included $40$% profit is $70$ euros,
- Old selling price not included profit is $50$ euros, at this point it is correct.

An extra thing you will need is the original profit is worth $20$ euros, but after the discount, the price is now only $63$ euros (which you also did correctly), so:

- New selling price not including profit: $63 \div 1.4 =45$ euros
- Profit of the new selling price: $63-45=18$ euros

The old selling price profit is $20$ euros, but the new selling price profit is $18$ euros, so the profit is decreased by $10$%.